# Why plane cannot be weight painted?

Tags: modeling, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

Can someone please explain to me why those two identical planes behave differently? Plane 1 can be weightpainted, while Plane 0 can't. I appended those planes from an important project file I am working on and deleted all the vertex groups, modifiers, color attributes, geo-scatter system, etc. Some of those things can't be copied to another plane (or at least I don't know how a simple way), so it would be awesome if someone found the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the second plane is on face masking mode in weight paint, and you don't have any faces selected.

[image]

Either disable face masking, or select some faces.  While using a masking mode, it will only paint on selected vertices (since faces don't really have weights, face masking mode is more like an accident of using the same code as they use for vertex color painting, like "hard light" blend mode in weight paint.)

[image]